# unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php

I am getting this error when I run php -v:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mcrypt.dll' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mcrypt.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: add output "ls /usr/lib64/php/modules/*mcrypt*"

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify whether mcrypt.so exists:

```
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so
```

Then change the php.ini line:

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

to:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

If it does not exist, install libmcrypt and php-mcrypt:

```
 wget ftp://mcrypt.hellug.gr/pub/crypto/mcrypt/libmcrypt/libmcrypt-2.5.7.tar.gz
 rpmbuild -ta libmcrypt-2.5.7.tar.gz
 rpm -ivh /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/libmcrypt-2.5.7-1.i386.rpm /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/libmcrypt-devel-2.5.7-1.i386.rpm
 yum --enablerepo=centosplus install php-mcrypt
```

I recommending using Ubuntu for easy installation of PHP, the PHP modules, and a web server. The Ubuntu repository includes FAR more packages and you do not need to connect other repositories and compile applications.

Comment: mcrypt.so exists and I already add that line in php.ini before, still  the error exists

Comment: delete "extension=php_mcrypt.dll" line from php.ini

Comment: ok, now it gives me a warning:

PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: delete duplication "extension=mcrypt.so" line

Comment: there is only one

Comment: run "find /etc/ -type f -exec grep mcrypt {} \; -print" to find duplication

Comment: ;extension=mcrypt.so
/etc/php.ini
Binary file /etc/ld.so.cache matches
/etc/ld.so.cache
; Enable mcrypt extension module
extension=mcrypt.so
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini

I have deleted the one in php.ini as you can see above, is that okay?

Comment: Yes. Comment line in one file.

Comment: if you dont' mind answering... I got the following on phpMySQL "Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration."

Comment: "php -i | grep mcrypt"

Comment: /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,

mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value

Comment: restart httpd: service httpd restart

Comment: Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 50.56.81.42 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down

Comment: "lsof -n -i :80"

Comment: that lsof command is not supported in centOS

Comment: netstat -anp | grep "\:80"

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22890/nginx.conf

Comment: use only apache or nginx to listen 80 port

Comment: I only have nginx installed... nothing else.. no apache in my system

Comment: maybe you can continue to help me at this link http://serverfault.com/questions/240891/phpmyadmin-setup-issues so I can reward you with more points.. thanks for helping