# phpMyAdmin setup issues

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/controluser) to setup the user and pass. It says there that "this section is only applicable if your MySQL server is running with --skip-show-database". First question is, how do I check if MySQl server is running with --skip-show-database?

Is there any way I can access phpMyAdmin SQL query window without logging in? Otherwise I'd have to execute this SQL from command line.

I am also getting this:

***Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration.***

I have added mcrypt.so to php.ini and doing the following command proves that I have it.

```
[root@DT html]# rpm -qa | grep mcrypt
mcrypt-2.6.8-1.el5
php-mcrypt-5.3.5-1.1.w5
libmcrypt-2.5.8-4.el5.centos
[root@DT html]# php -v
PHP 5.3.5 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2011 13:10:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Now when I go to phpinfo() and search for mcrypt it can find it inside the Configure Command row ('--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr'). So, what to do next?.

UPDATE:
I didn't put `extension=mcrypt.so` in php.ini as it will complain the following:

```
PHP Warning: Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  2;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            #root   html;
        }


        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            #root           /usr/local/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script                                                                                                                               _name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: Can you add your nginx config file here?

Comment: I've added my config... I don't actually have a phpmyadmin under a new server config... should I have it?

Comment: You check phpinfo() in nginx or conlose(cli)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create script /usr/local/nginx/html/test_mcrypt.php:

```
<?php
 var_dump(function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt'));
?>
```

Then open http://servername/test_mcrypt.php. If your see bool(true), then problem in web browser cache.

Then edit /usr/local/nginx/html/test_mcrypt.php:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

And find mcrupt section

Comment: I am getting false here.. where is that libraries/auth/cookie.auth.lib.php? I am now using ubuntu

Comment: Look like mcrypt module don't load. Check phpinfo(), I update answer.

Comment: no mcrypt find there anywhere

Comment: Add to "/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini" line "extension=mcrypt.so" and restart php

Comment: it says the loaded config file is /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, is there something wrong

Comment: I added mcrypt.so to this php.ini as well and it still doesn't shows up

Comment: I am sorry. Have you /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mcrypt.ini file?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: ls -al /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58 Mar 23  2010 /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

Comment: cat /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

Comment: it has that extension=mcrypt.so

Comment: What loader configuration file in phpinfo()?

Comment: I got it fixed by rebooting the server

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the users on [this post](http://www.question-defense.com/2009/06/18/phpmyadmin-error-cannot-load-mcrypt-extension-please-check-your-php-configuration) ran into similar problems; have you restarted Apache, and tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: I am using nginx not apache... I have restart it like many2 times. Tried on 2 different computers and same issue

Comment: Ah, `s/Apache/nginx/`; principle is the same, since the issue is with PHP, not the web server. :)  I'm sorry that wasn't the issue... I'll see if I can't find anymore solutions.